# On the definition of neighborhood and Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology

Until now, I've seen two definitions for a neighborhood on a topological space X:

> - Given an open set U and a point x in X,  U is a neighborhood of x if $x\in U $.
> - Given an open set U and a point x in X, $A\subseteq X$ is a neighborhood of x if $x\in U\subseteq A$.

This ambiguity led me to some doubts envolving the separation axioms. We say that a space follows the *$T_2$* axiom- being called a Hausdorff space- if, for any two points in this space, there is a neighborhood of one of them that doens't contain the other.

My question is: which definition is used here to describe a Hausdorff space? Is it the second one? If yes, does it imply that all Kolmogorov spaces are Hausdorff?

Comment: The second definition is incorrect.

Comment: I might call the first type of set an *open* neighborhood, to distinguish from the second type of set.  For a Hausdorff space, we require that any two points are contained in non-intersecting *open* sets.  That is, if $x,y\in X$, then there exist open sets $U,V\subseteq X$ such that $x\in U$, $y\in V$, and $U\cap V = \emptyset$.

Comment: for the purposes of separation, aren't the two equivalent? If you have a $U$, then you can take $A = U$ and you have $A$ as well. If you have an $A$, that already implies by definition there is a $U$ included in it.

Comment: You can use either to define Hausdorff since the first implies the second. I prefer the first myself.

Comment: Here is the (also language-wise) correct definition: A set $A\subset X$ is a neighborhood of $x\in X$ if there exists an open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\subset A$.

Comment: My problem involves the fact that the first definition implies the second, but not vice versa. However, if the definition of a Hausdorff space uses the first one, wouldn't it be the same as a Kolmogorov space?

Comment: as definitions of "nighbourhood" they are not equivalent, but as used in the definition of Hausdorff spaces, they are equivalent

Comment: Thank you all for answering the question. Now, I think it has been solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $A=U$ in the second definition and that gives the equivalence between the two statements.

Note that we also have the following inclusions:

$T_4 -\text{spaces} \subset T_3 -\text{spaces}\subset T_2 -\text{spaces} = \text{Hausdorff} \subset T_1 -\text{spaces}\subset T_0 -\text{spaces} = \text{Kolmogorov spaces}$.

However The excluded point topology on any set with at least two elements is $T_0$ but not $T_1$ and hence cannot be $T_2$. The only closed point is the excluded point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really solved most of the problem!

Answer (score 0):

N is a nhood of x when x in $N^o$, the interior of N.
There is little need for not open neighborhoods in topology today. In the developement of topology it seems nhoods were used to get a sense of the limit concepts they were generalizing.